# SQL Server Table/Index for storing Images

Tags: sql-server, image, performance, indexing

I am having some problems with storing Images in our database. We currently have about 400k records but I expect this to increase into the millions quite quickly. At the moment I am already experiencing performance issues so this is a major concern. I did a bit of research before deciding to use SQL Server to store the images and everything i read indicated that it would be capable of doing this.

I designed the table to be very simple containing 3 columns...

- Id (Primary Key, unique identifier, not null)
- ImageHash (unique identifier, not null)
- BinaryImage (varbinary(max), not null)

The logic was that I generate the ImageHash in my application code. The image hash is used for lookups before an insert to see if the binary image already exists in the database. The rest of the time I am simply querying the table using the Id directly.

I am using .NET Entity Framework to perform my Data Access. The Id column is being generated on insert, not sure if that is best practice or not.

Here is the Create Script of my Table. I created an index for the ImageHash, however I don't really have a great understanding of SQL Server Indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ImageContent](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [ImageHash] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [BinaryImage] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ImageData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ImageContent] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ImageData_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
```

And the Index....

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ImageHash_Index] ON [dbo].[ImageContent]
(
    [ImageHash] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Id]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have rebuilt all the indexes but that has not resolved the issue. I have been playing around with SQL Server Profiler and I identified SQL Insert that was causing the problem (Generated from Entity Framework). Here is the statement with the binary but I have truncated the majority of it with ... This was timing out after 30 seconds...

```
exec sp_executesql N'declare @generated_keys table([Id] uniqueidentifier)
insert [dbo].[ImageContent]([ImageHash], [BinaryImage])
output inserted.[Id] into @generated_keys
values (@0, @1)
select t.[Id]
from @generated_keys as g join [dbo].[ImageContent] as t on g.[Id] = t.[Id]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 varbinary(max) ',@0='DF76D1FF-5C05-58E0-0933-1ADBCC6345A8',@1=0xFFD8FFE1214545786966000049492A00080000000D00000103...
```

So my question are...

- Can anyone see some major issues with the way I have set this up?
- Are there any recommendations that you can give me to help me improve the performance?
- Is SQL Server capable of storing millions of images in this way?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: There is another issue with EF and `sp_executesql()` which sometimes takes place on execution (it depends on Linq expression input parameters). You could use SP to get rid of that. SQL is surely capable of storing millions of files per table.

Answer (score 2):

Because your indexes (including the clustered index on the primary key) are on uniqueidentifiers, these indices will fragment very quickly.

1. Consider a monotonically increasing INT/BIGINT IDENTITY as your Id, unless you have good reason to do otherwise
2. Adjust the fill factor on the NCI (ImageHash_Index) and make sure you have a job to reorganize/rebuild it regularly
3. Consider using FILESTREAM to store the actual images, if they are larger than 2 MB.  There is a whitepaper here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh461480.  If you go this route, two other performance considerations.  Information about them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377058(v=bts.10).aspx.

> Disable short-file-name (8.3) generation 
>   When a long file name is
>   created using the Windows NTFS file system, the default behavior is to
>   generate a corresponding short file name in the older 8.3 DOS file
>   name convention for compatibility with older operating systems. This
>   functionality can be disabled through a registry entry, offering a
>   performance increase.

fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1

> Disable NTFS last access updates 
>   Each file and folder on an NTFS
>   volume includes an attribute called Last Access Time. This attribute
>   shows when the file or folder was last accessed, such as when a user
>   performs a folder listing, adds files to a folder, reads a file, or
>   makes changes to a file. Maintaining this information creates
>   performance overhead for the file system especially in environments
>   where a large number of files and directories are accessed quickly and
>   in a short period of time, for example when using the BizTalk File
>   Adapter. Apart from in highly secure environments, retaining this
>   information might add a burden to a server that can be avoided by
>   updating the following registry key:

fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1

Comment: Thanks for you quick response Mark. It would be a big inconvenience for me to change all my primary key columns from uniqueidentifers to bigints. Do you think I would get the same benefit from using the SQL Server function NewSequentialID()? From what i have read this will generate a sequential uniqueidentifier which will then be inserted at the end of the index which prevents constant rebuilding on inserts. Does this sound like a good solution?

Comment: It could help in your case, but other issues can show up, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx). If you are fine with that, test it and use it.

Comment: NB: 2 MB is based on the whitepaper, which is the size at which FILESTREAM performs faster than BLOBs (page 8)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do due diligence and collect at least some minimal info, as it is is anybody' guess what the problem is. First thing you need to do is to read [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) to familiarize yourself with a proper investigation technique for troubleshooting SQL Server performanc eproblems and apply that methodology to collect the relevant information.

Now here is my opinion, which is based on no evidence whatsoever. Your INSERT is likely blocking and we cannot know why. Use the [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to understand what blocks your INSERT. This is not caused by fragmentation (the eternal [red herring](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/31/the-bizzaro-guide-to-sql-server-performance/)). If I would venture a guess, the culprit is use of default scope new System.Transactions and the [awful serialization isolation this brings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx).

As a side note: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is a horrible data type choice for a hash. To generate  a hash that is somehow relevant for the image you must run an hash algorithm, like MD5 or SHA. You're probably using MD5 and generating a 16 bytes key, but that is absolutely no reason to store it in a 16 byte length `UNIQEUIDENTIFIER` type. Use `BINARY(16)`. Also condsider if you want to move to SHA1 (20 bytes hash) or other hash in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I decided to use UNIQUEIDENTIFIER to store the hash as I believed this would be better to index than a BINARY(16). Is this not correct?

Comment: No, is incorrect. An index on BINARY(16) has exactly the same characteristics as an index on `CHAR(16)`, an index on `NCHAR(8)` or one uniqueidentifier. Is a fixed size key of length 16.